# Would it make any security risk if I send last URL accessed with reset password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, security

Would it make any security risk if I send the last URL accessed with reset password email to redirect the user to that page after resetting? Primarily our reset password system has these steps below. I will have to make chane in ask for new password step here. I already have a return URL in the login page.

Steps:
ask for a new password --> you will receive a link on e-mail --> click on the link --> make new password --> save the password --> you are logged in and redirect to the home page. I have used .net to implement email sending mechanism

Comment: I don't think that this would pose a security risk.  As long as the redirect URL is relative to your own website and not a full URL...  If it was a full URL then _someone else_ could request someone to change their password, spoof the referrer header and send a person to their servers (or anywhere else) after redirect.

Comment: I will send the request URL for my site in an email to reset the password. So, if I send the returnUrl(where they will go after resetting the password) as relative URL, it won't make any problem you are saying if I understood you correctly?

Comment: Yes, if it's relative it's likely to be very low risk.